# Is it Possible to use all product categories to create a menu automatically on wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I just imported  bunch of product categories to wordpress/woocommerce. I want to use all these categories to create a menu and then assign it to a menu location.

Unfortunately wordpress does not order the categories for me in the on the nav menu screen. here is an example image [Nav menu page shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSPO8.png)
Category baby should have alot more clild categorybelow but they are all scattered and it is A LOT of categories to reorder. So I just want to automatically use them all to create a menu in the same order they were created. parent and child.

If anybody has a solution to order them from the section in the image above that would be good too. As I could select them in bulk and add.
Thank you

Comment: yes, by using Walker Nav Menu. we can set drop down menu as per your recruitment. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker